# SQL: Get SUM of grouped query having count statement

Tags: sql, count, sum, having

I'm looking for a query that counts all entries which have more than 1 entry.
e.g.:

```
   adrnr   value   datum
   15      8.68    2021-08-29
   10      16.4    2021-08-30
   15      33.6    2021-08-30
   16      125.98  2021-08-31
   10      23.44   2021-08-31
   18      19.87   2021-08-31
   16      26.87   2021-09-01
   10      10.0    2021-09-01
```

I came up with following query:

```
SELECT adrnr, COUNT(adrnr) as summe FROM tablename WHERE datum >= '2021-01-08 00:00:00.000' 
AND datum <= '2021-31-08 23:59:59.999' group by adrnr having count(adrnr) > 1
```

I then get an answer:

```
   adrnr  summe
   15     2
   10     2
```

This is fine, but I want to get just one SUM of all entries, i.e.:

```
summe
4
```

How do I get this answer. And after that I want to get the the SUM of all values that depends on the same condition, i.e. 82.12
Any idea?

Regards Jens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery against your current query:

```
SELECT SUM(summe)
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(adrnr) AS summe
    FROM tablename
    WHERE datum >= '2021-08-01' AND datum < '2021-09-01'
    GROUP BY adrnr
    HAVING COUNT(drnr) > 1
) t;
```

Note: Your timestamp/date literals looked a bit off.  The above assumes you only want to target the month of August, 2021.

Comment: woah. This was a fast answer. Thanks a lot. Didn't saw the solution by my own. Yes, my date literals could be better.